# How to reset my IntelliJ IDEA plugins to default?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm using IntelliJ and I installed almost every plugin available on the repositories, now my IntelliJ is slow.

Is there a way I can reset my IntelliJ plugins to the default ones?

Comment: You can delete the whole .idea folder - this will reset all of your settings: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: @Kootli It worked, thanks! If you submit it as an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the whole .idea folder - this will reset all of your settings: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 0):

In 2019.1 you can edit the ~/.IntelliJIdea2019.1/config/disabled_plugins.txt file